# Get Maximum score in the same id and then compare with other id

Tags: php, mysql

table :

```
========================================
|id| document_id | sentence_id | score |
========================================
|1 |   3         |     1       | 0.324 |
|2 |   3         |     2       | 0.201 |
|3 |   5         |     1       | 0.181 |
|4 |   5         |     2       | 0.402 |
========================================
```

I wanna get maximum score in every `document_id` and then compare the result with other `document_id`. My goal is to get the sequence of `document_id. so from the example, the result must be 5 3`

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT document_id, MAX(score) as max_score FROM `tb_score` GROUP BY document_id ");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {
   $min = $row['max_score'];
}
```

I still get a wrong result. Please, help me.

Comment: "I still get wrong result" isn't helping us diagnose the problem.  You should post your exact result (possibly with your exact data set) and your expected result so we can compare and contrast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can't use alias](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/order-by-optimization.html) [in `ORDER BY`](http://www.geeksww.com/tutorials/database_management_systems/mysql/tips_and_tricks/mysql_dateformat_function_and_order_by.php). So you have to use `MAX(score)` in `ORDER BY`. Like this:

```
SELECT document_id ,MAX(score) as Highscore
FROM tb_score
GROUP BY document_id
ORDER BY MAX(score) DESC;
```

OR using sub-query you can do the same.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT document_id ,MAX(score) as Highscore
FROM tb_score
GROUP BY document_id
) A
ORDER BY Highscore DESC;
```

## [*See this SQLFiddle*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f8171/4)

Answer (score 1):

The SQL you seemed to describe is:

```
SELECT document_id
        , MAX(score) as max_score
    FROM tb_score
    GROUP BY document_id
    ORDER BY MAX(score) DESC --or max_score, I'm not sure which MySQL will accept.
```

Does that help?

Aside:  [MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) extensions are deprecated in PHP, you should use [MySQL Improved](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PHP Data Objects](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) to do this job.

Answer (score 1):

The SQL must be like this.

```
SELECT document_id, MAX(score) as max_score 
FROM `tb_score` GROUP BY document_id
ORDER BY max_score DESC
```